# WinUsb ControlTransfer on USB 3.0

Tags: c++, usb, winusb

I'm currently learning by doing programming a USB device.
But unfortunately i came across some problems that might came through not knowing everything.

The situation is I queried my device via ControlTransfer, since this works like a charm on USB 2.0 it doesn't on USB 3.0. So therefore I'm trying to understand why it fails. Is there any minor change from USB 2.0 to USB 3.0?

Comment: I am pretty sure USB 3.0 still has control transfers, since it is such a basic part of the protocol and these changes are usually backwards compatible. You should look for the answer elsewhere.  It might be a weird driver bug somewhere in your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if anyone else runs into that problem if found the solution.

So the situation was, the device had an 8 byte package from that i only needed the first 2 bytes.

On USB 2.0 i could give control transfer the buffer with length parameter 2. (Buffer with 2 Byte length)

On USB 3.0 the buffer remains the same, but i have to submit the length of the package waiting on the device (in this case 8).